# Test module 'isa-ok' with Buf

Tags: testing, raku

Using the Perl6 `Test` module to test an object's type with `Buf`:

```
use Test;
isa-ok Buf.new, Buf;
isa-ok Buf.new, Blob;
isa-ok Buf.new, 'Buf';
isa-ok Buf.new, 'Blob';
ok Buf.new ~~ Buf;
ok Buf.new ~~ Blob;
does-ok Buf.new, Buf;
does-ok Buf.new, Blob;
```

Here's the output:

```
not ok 1 - The object is-a 'Buf'
# Failed test 'The object is-a 'Buf''
# at buftest line 3
# Actual type: Buf
not ok 2 - The object is-a 'Blob'
# Failed test 'The object is-a 'Blob''
# at buftest line 5
# Actual type: Buf
ok 3 - The object is-a '"Buf"'
not ok 4 - The object is-a '"Blob"'
# Failed test 'The object is-a '"Blob"''
# at buftest line 9
# Actual type: Buf
ok 5 - 
ok 6 - 
ok 7 - The object does role 'Buf'
ok 8 - The object does role 'Blob'
```

How does `isa-ok` really work?  How does that differ from just `~~`?
What is the difference between testing an object against `Buf` vs. `'Buf'`?
Why isn't a `Buf` considered to be `isa` a `Buf` or `Blob`? (while it `isa` a `'Buf'` but still not a `'Blob'`?

In general, does `isa-ok` understand roles or must `does-ok` be used for them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [`isa-ok` does not work with parametrized types](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/2656). (I think the issue title is misleading because aiui it's really about classes vs roles not parameterized vs unparamaterized types. One can write `Array[Int]` after all and that's arguably a parameterized type.)

I found this by [searching the Rakudo Github repo for 'isa-ok'](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=isa-ok&type=Issues) and clicking on `Issues`.

[Mu.pm6](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/master/src/core/Mu.pm6) defines `isa`:

```
proto method isa(|) {*}

multi method isa(Mu \SELF: Mu $type --> Bool:D) {
    nqp::hllbool(SELF.^isa($type.WHAT))
}

multi method isa(Mu \SELF: Str:D $name --> Bool:D) {
    return True if .^name eq $name for SELF.^mro;
    False
}
```

The first multi only works if the type is a class. In P6 the word "isa" has a technical meaning that `A isa B` iff both `A` and `B` are *classes* and `A` is, or *inherits* from, `B`.

(More concretely, the `isa` of a class that does `Perl6::Metamodel::MROBasedTypeChecking` resolves to a method in the corresponding `role` that checks for a match based on going through the class's method resolution order.)

A type like `Buf` is a role. (Roles can be easily "punned" into corresponding anonymous classes/instances by, eg. `Buf.new`, but that doesn't stop `Buf` itself being a role.)

A type like `Array` works because `Array` is a class.

So:

```
put Array.HOW.^name; # Perl6::Metamodel::ClassHOW+{<anon>}
say Array.^mro;      # ((Array) (List) (Cool) (Any) (Mu))
isa-ok Array, List;  # ok
put Buf.HOW.^name;   # Perl6::Metamodel::ParametricRoleGroupHOW
say Buf.^mro;        # No such method 'mro' for invocant of type
                     # 'Perl6::Metamodel::ParametricRoleGroupHOW'
```

The string version of `isa-ok` applies only if you pass a string version of the type's name. For good or ill it allows for a sloppier way of thinking about types and will accept an exact match.

`~~` is "smart matching". It's up to the type on the right to decide if the thing on the left is to be considered a match.

> In general, does `isa-ok` understand roles or must `does-ok` be used for them?

No it doesn't. You should use `does-ok`.